# Htaccess to hide subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, forward

Hope someone can help. I am trying to hide the subdomain /submain/so that www.website.com/home.php will point to www.website.com/submain/home.php but will only show www.website.com/home.php.
I have tried a few different options but it either breaks my css files or the page keeps looping.

Also to mention my css folder is within the submain folder. This keeps breaking when i get the code to work.
current code

```
#redirect to submain subdomain
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /submain/
RewriteRule ^submain/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule !^submain/ submain%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

I also want the reverse so that urls with submain is hidden only showing www.website.com